# Kubernetes: Should the API port be exposed as a recommended security practice

Tags: api, kubernetes

Judging from what I can see, exposure of the API kubernetes can be especially risky. It seems there are be methods for protecting this, but I am hesitant to consider these as adequate solutions .

I am thinking that I should just ssh tunnel to access this port and not expose it externally. Is it enough to protect it with RBAC and certs?

What would be the recommend practice for exposing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common protection is adding a VPN-Layer on top of the RBAC.
That makes it easy to use standard VPN access control and distribution models for a larger group of developers.

You could also use a bastion host that controls API access via an identity aware reverse proxy, e.g. Google IAP.
Then you can use your standard identity provider like AzureAD including MFA .

I would not recommend SSH-ing since this form of access control does not scale well and lacks observability.